# Interpolate between functions a(i) and b(j) in a Neural Network

Tags: r

I am trying to use nnet function in R to approximate the function of two variables y(a,b). Both variable, "a" and "b are known at fixed points:

```
a={a(1),a(2),...,a(i),...a(n)} and
b={b(1),b(2),...,b(i),...b(n)}.
```

The value of "y" function is known for each pair a(i),b(i), i.e.

```
y(a,b)={y(a(1),b(1)),y(a(2),b(2),...y(a(i),b(i),...y(a(n),b(n)}.
```

I make

```
res=nnet(y~a+b,size=X,maxit=M,linout=TRUE),
```

where X and M are defined.

How can I get value of result between the points, for example at some a- value, which is between a(i) and a(i+1) and b-value, which is between b(j) and b(j+1) ?

Comment: If you want to make a prediction with new data you just have to use: predict(res,...). See '?predict'. Was that your question

Comment: I think there's a 2D-spline tool somewhere, but can't track it down.  But until then,  as sdir said just use `predict` on the fitted object you just created.

Comment: This would be a much higher value question if you posed a test case.

Comment: If I make new vector, for example "a1" and "b1" with desired points inside at which I want to get result with "predict(res,..)", the system says, that the size of "a" and "a1" is different. If I make "a1" and "b1" with the same number of points, as "a" and "b" but with new points, the result of "predict" is obviously incorrect.May be I use "predict" incorrectly, in this case, how it should look like ? res1=predict(res,a1,b1) ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like proper naming problem. I suggest using `data.frame`s in order to prevent misunderstandings.

```
library(nnet)
X <- 20  # Number of neurons in hidden layer
M <- 1e4 # Maximum number of iterations
N <- 50  # Length of data vectors

set.seed(1)
## Train set
df.train <- data.frame(a=rnorm(N,5,1), b=rnorm(N,10,2))
df.train$y <- with(df.train, 5*a-2*b+rnorm(N))
## Test set for interpolation
a1 <- sapply(2:N, function(i) with(df.train, (a[i]+a[i-1])/2))
b1 <- sapply(2:N, function(i) with(df.train, (b[i]+b[i-1])/2))
df.test <- data.frame(a=a1, b=b1)
```

The code above creates two `data.frame`s:

1. `df.train` with columns `a`, `b` and `y`.
2. `df.test` with columns `a` and `b`.

Note, that columns' names for variables should coincide in both `data.frame`s.

Training:

```
res <- nnet(y~a+b, data=df.train, size=X, maxit=M, linout=TRUE)
p1 <- predict(res, df.train)
```

Here `p1` is prediction for training data.

Interpolation:

```
p2 <- predict(res, df.test)
```

Visually, interpolation looks quite natural:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(aes(x,y), data=data.frame(x=1:N, y=df.train$y)) +        # original y
  geom_point(aes(x,y), data=data.frame(x=1.5:N, y=p2), colour="red") # interpolations
```

[image]